# Efficient URL Escape (Percent-Encoding)

Tags: java, performance, url, escaping

Here I have a simple algorithm to percent-encode any string.

(Specification from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding); note that this is not compatible with `URLEncoder.encode()`)

Is this an efficient solution to the problem?

Using a `StringBuilder` *should* be efficient, but it doesn't seem great since every character is added to the `StringBuilder` individually.  Could this have any significant impact?

This method works only for ASCII characters; that is sufficient for my use case.

```
private static String urlEscape(String toEscape){
    //if null, keep null (no gain or loss of safety)
    if (toEscape==null)
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for (char character: toEscape.toCharArray())//for every character in the string
        switch (character){//if the character needs to be escaped, add its escaped value to the StringBuilder
        case '!': sb.append("%21"); continue;
        case '#': sb.append("%23"); continue;
        case '$': sb.append("%24"); continue;
        case '&': sb.append("%26"); continue;
        case '\'': sb.append("%27"); continue;
        case '(': sb.append("%28"); continue;
        case ')': sb.append("%29"); continue;
        case '*': sb.append("%2A"); continue;
        case '+': sb.append("%2B"); continue;
        case ',': sb.append("%2C"); continue;
        case '/': sb.append("%2F"); continue;
        case ':': sb.append("%3A"); continue;
        case ';': sb.append("%3B"); continue;
        case '=': sb.append("%3D"); continue;
        case '?': sb.append("%3F"); continue;
        case '@': sb.append("%40"); continue;
        case '[': sb.append("%5B"); continue;
        case ']': sb.append("%5D"); continue;
        case ' ': sb.append("%20"); continue;
        case '"': sb.append("%22"); continue;
        case '%': sb.append("%25"); continue;
        case '-': sb.append("%2D"); continue;
        case '.': sb.append("%2E"); continue;
        case '<': sb.append("%3C"); continue;
        case '>': sb.append("%3E"); continue;
        case '\\': sb.append("%5C"); continue;
        case '^': sb.append("%5E"); continue;
        case '_': sb.append("%5F"); continue;
        case '`': sb.append("%60"); continue;
        case '{': sb.append("%7B"); continue;
        case '|': sb.append("%7C"); continue;
        case '}': sb.append("%7D"); continue;
        case '~': sb.append("%7E"); continue;
        default: sb.append(character);//if it does not need to be escaped, add the character itself to the StringBuilder
        }
    return sb.toString();//build the string, and return
}
```

Comment: Won't this fail with UTF-8 characters?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, this will fail for special characters.  However, it's not important for my use case.

Comment: That should be specified in the question.

Comment: Also have a look at this SO answer (and the other answer): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4605848/866915

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are in **dire** need of a lookup table. What you want to do is define a mapping somewhere else, and then just percent-encode all characters you have mapped. This gets rid of that unwieldy, huge and btw. hacky switch-statement.

consider the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(toEncode.length());
for (Character c : toEncode.toCharArray()) {
    if (MAPPING.containsKey(c)) {
       sb.append(MAPPING.get(c));
    } else {
       sb.append(c);
    }
}
```

This should be equally fast, if not faster. Also it makes use of a MAPPING you can change, without significantly affecting how this method works. btw. I am prespecifying the StringBuilder's capacity, since it's more efficient when the backing collection in there does not need to be resized too often.

Oh and another thing. Your switch-case only works by sheer luck. `continue;` is not the correct keyword to use there, instead you should rely on `break;` that allows you to add more work in the loop body, which is currently more or less impossible.

Comment: Would it be worth adding roughly +10% capacity to the StringBuilder?

Comment: @Builder_K depends a little on what you are encoding, and you'd have to run measurements.... It depends

Comment: Some mapping implementations also have a 'get or default value' function, which would eliminate the needs for an `if` statement. In Java 8 even the default map implementation has this.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to put your list of reserved characters as a `String`, then iterate-and-compare using `indexOf()`:

```
private static final String VALUES = "!#$&'()*+,/:;=?@[] \"%-.<>\\^_`{|}~";

private static String encode(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
        return input;
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input);
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (VALUES.indexOf(input.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            result.replace(i, i + 1, 
                    "%" + Integer.toHexString(input.charAt(i)).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

You may want to (slightly) optimize your initial validation by skipping `""` values as well. Over here, I used `input` as the initial contents of the `StringBuilder`. Helpfully, the *initial capacity* adds another 16 on top of the input's length, so if there's only... 8 replacements, then it's pretty 'efficient' (for some definition of that word).

Also, take note that the iteration is done from the *end* of the `String`, to preserve the `start` positioning of the character to replace. To visualize this in another manner, the replacement is always done to the *right*, while moving *left*-wise.

Comment: VALUES.indexOf() is O(n) time. A lookup (let's assume hash) table is theoretically faster, with O(1) time.

Comment: The `VALUES` string is of course very useful to the function you write that builds the lookup table (once, on first use).

Comment: @Builder_K Big O notation is only important for asymptotic performance. With a constant set of items it's completely irrelavant. There may be a performance penalty to iterating through the array, but it's so small it's insignificant. Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

Comment: @AnubianNoob actually not "completely irrelevant". but you do have a point. for this use-case O(n) and O(1) are the same since n is constant ...

Comment: @AnubianNoob I guess I'm used to thinking in big O estimates.  All I meant was that iterating over the string many times will incur a performance hit.

Comment: @Builder_K It's not as much of a hit so much as a tap. [Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) is far worse...